# How to realize it's time to tune the parameters of the optimizer instead of other parameter like network architecture?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization

I know the basic meaning of the parameters of general optimizers. However, I find I rarely know when it's the time to tune them and how to appropriately tune these parameters, such as $\beta1$, $\beta2$ and $\epsilon$ in Adam -- all I know is to tune learning rate when the network learns too slow or the training process is chattering.

Therefore I'm wondering what evidence can provide a clue to say that it's time to tune the parameters of the optimizer instead of other parameters like network architecture?